# Use 'LIKE' in an INSERT statement to describe the records from a dblink'ed SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to simplify the following final statement:

```
DROP TABLE asdf;

CREATE TABLE asdf (LIKE calibrations);

INSERT INTO asdf (rid, pid, status, cal_date, project_name, username,
  sensor_type, serial_number, var_name, dsm_name, cal_type, channel,
  gainbplr, ads_file_name, set_times, set_points, averages, stddevs, cal,
  temperature, comment)
  SELECT * FROM dblink(
    'host=remoteserv user=auser password=hello dbname=cals',
    'SELECT * FROM calibrations WHERE username=\'JAM\'') AS
      t(rid character varying(20), pid character varying(20),
        status character(3), cal_date timestamp,
        project_name character varying(32), username character varying(32),
        sensor_type character varying(20), sn character varying(20),
        var_name character varying(20), dsm_name character varying(16),
        cal_type character varying(16), channel character(1),
        gainbplr character(2), ads_file_name character varying(40),
        set_times timestamp[], set_points double precision[],
        averages double precision[], stddevs double precision[],
        cal double precision[], temperature double precision,
        comment character varying(256));
```

I was able to simplify the last statement as such:

```
INSERT INTO asdf 
  SELECT * FROM dblink(
    'host=remoteserv user=auser password=hello dbname=cals',
    'SELECT * FROM calibrations WHERE username=\'JAM\'') AS
      t(rid character varying(20), pid character varying(20),
        status character(3), cal_date timestamp,
        project_name character varying(32), username character varying(32),
        sensor_type character varying(20), sn character varying(20),
        var_name character varying(20), dsm_name character varying(16),
        cal_type character varying(16), channel character(1),
        gainbplr character(2), ads_file_name character varying(40),
        set_times timestamp[], set_points double precision[],
        averages double precision[], stddevs double precision[],
        cal double precision[], temperature double precision,
        comment character varying(256));
```

Is it possible to write the last statement as something like this?

```
INSERT INTO asdf 
  SELECT * FROM dblink(
    'host=remoteserv user=auser password=hello dbname=cals',
    'SELECT * FROM calibrations WHERE username=\'JAM\'') AS
      t(LIKE calibrations);
```

-- John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, dblink() function returns `setof record` and database needs to know the column list. This is mentioned in dblink documentation:

> The function returns the row(s) produced by the query. Since dblink can be used with 
>   any query, it is declared to return record, rather than specifying any particular 
>   set of columns. This means that you must specify the expected set of columns in the 
>   calling query — otherwise PostgreSQL would not know what to expect.

The `FROM` clause of `SELECT` statement has the following definition:

```
where from_item can be one of:

    [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ] ]
    ( select ) [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ]
    with_query_name [ [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ] ]
    function_name ( [ argument [, ...] ] ) [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] | column_definition [, ...] ) ]
    function_name ( [ argument [, ...] ] ) AS ( column_definition [, ...] )
    from_item [ NATURAL ] join_type from_item [ ON join_condition | USING ( join_column [, ...] ) ]
```